# Scoped ViewModel with Dagger Hilt in a Dynamic Feature Module

Tags: android, dagger, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

I am following the official Android guide for [Using Dagger in multi-module apps](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-multi-module#dagger-dfm), and I am able to get everything to compile and "work".

The problem is that I have a viewpager in my dynamic feature module and I need to have a parent "scoped" viewmodel. The documentation shows this example of injecting a ViewModel

```
// You want Dagger to provide an instance of LoginViewModel from the Login graph
@Inject lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
```

While generally I use something like

```
val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.parentFragment)
```

Does anyone know of a way to properly scope a shared viewmodel?